# How to update rows based only on ROW_NUMBER()?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Such SQL query:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, YEAR order by ID ), ID, YEAR
from table t
```

give me following query set:

```
1   1000415591  2012
1   1000415591  2013
2   1000415591  2013
1   1000415591  2014
2   1000415591  2014
```

How could I update records with ROW_NUMBER() equals to 2? Other fields of this records is identically (`select distinct from table where id = 1000415591` gives 3 records when there are 5 without `distinct` keyword), so I can depend only on ROW_NUMBER() value.

I need solution for Oracle, because I saw something similar for SQL-Server but it won't work with Oracle.

Comment: could you add the something similar for SQL-Server, it might speed up things, Also what does your table look like exactly?

Comment: I tried creating a sqlfiddle but can't seem to get the same result with that query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/beafc/1

Comment: @JeremyC. Because your table name is incorrect. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/beafc/13

Comment: Just noticed that aswell but thanks :D, wasn't that the table name was incorrect it was the 'table' keyword that didn't belong there

Comment: @JeremyC. It seemed like you put an alias as "t" to table_name "table" ;-) Anyway, the table keyword was not required in FROM clause.

Comment: I know but I just took the query from the OP to get to the same starting position as he/she was on, didn't notice the extra table keyword :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [ROWID](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm) field:

```
UPDATE T
SET t.year = t.year*1000
WHERE (rowid,2) in (SELECT rowid,
                           ROW_NUMBER() 
                              OVER (PARTITION BY ID, t.YEAR order by ID ) 
                    FROM T)
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/50124/1)</kbd>

If you need to delete range of ROWNUMBERS then :

```
UPDATE T
SET t.year = t.year*1000
WHERE rowid in ( SELECT rowid FROM
                 ( 
                   SELECT rowid,
                           ROW_NUMBER() 
                              OVER (PARTITION BY ID, t.YEAR order by ID ) as RN
                    FROM T
                  ) T2 WHERE RN >=2 AND RN <=10
                  )
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3ca2c/1)</kbd>

Comment: It's close to what I need. But what if ROW_NUMBER() is between 2 and 10?

Comment: @Dracontis I added the second query for the range of row numbers

Comment: I've just adding same edition. Yes, it's what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a **MERGE** statement which is quite verbose and easy to understand.

For example,

```
MERGE INTO t s 
USING
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, YEAR order by ID ) RN,
  ID,
  YEAR
FROM TABLE t
) u ON (s.id = u.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET YEAR = some_value WHERE u.RN = 2)
/
```

**Note** You cannot merge the same column which is used to join in the ON clause.

Comment: This code cause ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

Comment: @Dracontis That's because the subquery isn't returning unique row, rather multiple rows. Focus on the USING clause and ON clause. I don't have your table data to reproduce your test case.

Comment: I've tried this SQL to sqlfiddle in comments above. Same ORA-30926 error as I've got with my table data.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the update statement but this is how to get the 2 rows you wanted to update:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, YEAR order by ID ) as rn, ID, YEAR
from t )
where rn = 2
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/beafc/43)

Comment: not 100% sure if this is usefull as I wouldn't know how to go about updating these rows now :s

Comment: Problem is that rows are different only with ROW_NUMBER() fields and they're identical without it.

Comment: you could try, creating a new table with primary_key, id and year, copying every row from your current table in the new table, run the query that I put up here to get the primary_key from that new table and run update on table where id IN the result from that query, might be a roundabout way of doing it but it's possible, this would mean you have to start using the new table though instead of the old one

Answer (score 0):

When I've posted thq question, I've found that this could be wrong approach. I could modify table and add new fields. So better solution to create one more field `IDENTITY` and update it with numbers from the new sequence from 1 to total row numbers. Then I could update fields based on this `IDENTIY` field.

I'll keep this question opened if someone come up with solution based on ROW_NUMBER() analytic function.

```
update TABLE set NEW_ID = TABLE_SEQ.nextval 
where IDENTITY in (
    select IDENTITY from (
        select row_number() over(PARTITION BY ID, YEAR order by ID) as row_num, t.ID, t."YEAR", t.IDENTITY
        from TABLE t
    ) where row_num > 1
)
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: This is answer, not addition to the question. It's possible solution when you need to update duplicate rows. But it's not correct and ideal solution, that's why I didn't mark it as answer.